# Getting output of a shell script in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, shell

Is there a way that lets me run a shell script, and display the output in an NSTextView? I do not want any input from the user to the shell script at all, since is is just called to compile a buch of files. The shell script part works fine so far, but I just can't figure out how to run it and show the output in an NSTextView. I know a shell script can be run using system() and NSTask, but how do I get it's output into an NSTextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want wildcard expansion then pass your unix command to /bin/sh

```
- (NSString *)unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn:(NSString *) command {
    // performs a unix command by sending it to /bin/sh and returns stdout.
    // trims trailing carriage return
    // not as efficient as running command directly, but provides wildcard expansion

    NSPipe *newPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [newPipe fileHandleForReading];
    NSData *inData = nil;
    NSString* returnValue = nil;

    NSTask * unixTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [unixTask setStandardOutput:newPipe];
    [unixTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/csh"];
    [unixTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", command , nil]]; 
    [unixTask launch];
    [unixTask waitUntilExit];
    int status = [unixTask terminationStatus];

    while ((inData = [readHandle availableData]) && [inData length]) {

        returnValue= [[NSString alloc] 
                      initWithData:inData encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

        returnValue = [returnValue substringToIndex:[returnValue length]-1];

        NSLog(@"%@",returnValue);
    }

    return returnValue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSTask` has `setStandardOutput` method that accepts either `NSFileHandle` or `NSPipe` object. So if you create `NSPipe` object and set it as `NSTask`'s `standardOutput` then you could use `NSPipe`'s `fileHandleForReading` to get `NSFileHandle` from which, in turn, you'll be able to `readDataToEndOfFile` or `readDataOfLength:` you want. So something like this would do (code untested):

```
- (void)setupTask {
  // assume it's an ivar
  standardOutputPipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
  [myTask setStandardOutput:standardOutputPipe];
  // other setup code goes below
}

// reading data to NSTextField
- (void)updateOutputField {
  NSFileHandle *readingFileHandle = [standardOutputPipe fileHandleForReading];
  NSData *newData;
  while ((newData = [readingFileHandle availableData])) {
    NSString *newString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:newData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSString *wholeString = [[myTextField stringValue] stringByAppendingString:newString];
    [myTextField setStringValue:wholeString];
  }
  [standardOutputPipe release];
  standardOutputPipe = nil;
}
```

Comment: Depending on how long the task will run, it may be better to read the data in the background, using one of NSFileHandle's methods for that.

Comment: I am basically doing what you say above, and running the update output field in the background using a thread, the task runs, but I never see anyrthing in the textview. It is wired up correctly. Here's the code for running in the background: '[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(updateOutputField:) toTarget:self withObject: nil];'
It shows the output in the debugger, but on in the text field. Launching it is like this:
[myTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
    [myTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:scr], nil]]; 
 [myTask setStandardOutput:standardOutputPipe];
    [myTask launch];